# ASP Identity Issue not authenticting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

So I'm using ASP Identity.  I customized the profile with adding isEnabled so that I know if a user is Active or not.  This works fine and the database is updated without issue.

So after research, I saw that I need to override "public async override Task PasswordSignInAsync" that I can check for the isEnabled property.  This works fine as well because it's passing the proper SigninStatus that I need to the Login Page.

The IdentifyConfig.cs File:

```
public async override Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, bool shouldLockout)
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(userName).Result;


        if (user.IsEnabled != false)
        {

            return await Task.FromResult<SignInStatus>(SignInStatus.Success);
        }

        return await Task.FromResult<SignInStatus>(SignInStatus.LockedOut);
    }
```

The Login Page:

```
protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid)
        {
            // Validate the user password
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

            // This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            //var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);
            var result = signinManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);

            switch (result.Result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    //IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
                    Response.Redirect("/Account/Dashboard");

                    break;
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");
                    break;
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}",
                                                    Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"],
                                                    RememberMe.Checked),
                                      true);
                    break;
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    //FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt";
                    //ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The switch case goes into the right case, but here's the issue. When it goes into the case SignInStatus.Success: it just stays in a loop and keeps presenting the Login Screen as if the user is not authenticated.  Now, I'm sure i am missing something on the Override for

```
public async override Task PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, bool shouldLockout)
```

function, but I thought if Success came back that the user is authorized.

If I uncomment

```
//var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);
```

function it works fine, but I can't get the `IsEnabled` value to check.  Please any advice would be appreciated on this issue.

Comment: Side note but you should avoid using `_.Result` for your async methods because they are thread blocking.  It is better to use `await _`, like `var result = await signinManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...);` and then just use `result` directly as `switch(result)`.  That is, unless you specifically _want_ to block the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that we have a few issues that are compounding for you, making this process a bit hard to dissect

- Your async implementation could cause some thread issues
- We want to be sure to handle a null situation on user lookup, for a bad username
- We want to be sure that we actually validate the password
- We need to call the method necessary to login the user as well, as that is a responsibility of this method

I'm going to assume that you are using the non ASP.NET Core version of things. As such, this modified version should help. I have not been able to 100% validate.

```
public async override Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, bool shouldLockout)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(userName);

        //User not found
        if (user == null)
            return SignInStatus.Failure; 

        //User not enabled
        if (user.IsEnabled != false)
            return SignInStatus.Failure; 

        //Now, validate that the password was correct
        var isValidPassword = await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);
        if (!isValidPassword)
            return SignInStatus.Failure; 

        //Now we know they are valid and enabled, login and return
        await base.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent, false);
        return SignInStatus.Success;
    }
```

This above code SHOULD work for you, without issue.  The only question is on the type that is used to pass into the CheckPassword asyc, I don't have a project ready to validate.  But this should get you there.